# How to assign value ng-model in array?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Following is controller code:

```
var app = angular.module("test",[]);
app.controller("testController", function($scope,$http){
    $scope.AccessArray = [];
    $scope.Data = [
        {"id":"1","Name":"Name1","Address":"Address1"}, 
        {"id":"2","Name":"Name2","Address":"Address2"}, 
        {"id":"3","Name":"Name3","Address":"Address3"}
    ];
    $scope.Assign = function(id){
        alert($scope.AccessArray[id]);
        $scope.AccessArray[id] = id;
    }

 });
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Task problem</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>value</td>
                    <td>Assign</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="dt in Data">
                    <td>{{dt.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{dt.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{dt.Address}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="FormData.AccessArray[dt.id]" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" ng-click="Assign(dt.id)" value="Assign"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script src="test.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click assign it should assign id to text box and it should alert position of record. But it is showing undefined. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: You are doing alert first (so value is undefined till now) then after you are assigning value (now the value will be defined). Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uwqs6pz3/

Comment: Okey got it thanks..:) but if I put before ng-model FormData attribute then?

Comment: ng-model FormData attribute is getter not the setter (Untill you start typing something). It will get the value, and the value is undefined now.
I have updated the fiddle. Check it http://jsfiddle.net/uwqs6pz3/1/

Comment: @intekhab thank you so much. this solution solved my problem...